# django template tag with value from from loop

Tags: python, django, django-templates

i have django tags  as {{ ques.0 }},{{ ques.1 }},{{ ques.2 }} and i wan't to display them using for loop something like this

```
{% for i in ques %}
     document.getElementById("opt1").innerHTML="{{ ques.i }}";
 {% end for %}
```

Its not displaying the data but when i put a value like {{ ques.0 }} it gives the result ,but how can i use it with for loop to display the data 
Basically i want to pass a value in tags using for loop

The main problem to to get value using tags that is generated using for loop in django

```
    x=5;
for(var i=0;i<x;i++){
                document.getElementById("question").innerHTML="{{ ques.i }}";
            }
```

Comment: just `{{ i }}` should do inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try using the dictionary? to store values in the form of Dictionary Keys and use it

```
dict1= {}
for i in range(3):
    dict1["ques.%d"%i] = 10

dict1
{'ques.0': 10, 'ques.1': 10, 'ques.2': 10}
```

You can try the same while retrieving

```
{% for keys in dict1 %}
    document.getElementById("opt1").innerHTML="{{keys}}";
{% end for %}
```

If anything wrong with that, let me know, please.